# In Safari, can a set of bookmarks in a folder be opened programmatically (e.g. using AppleScript)?

Tags: macos, applescript, safari, bookmarks

I have a set of bookmarks in a folder. Usually, I open them by selecting the folder  and then "Open in New Tabs". Is it possible to do this using a script? I imagine AppleScript would be the right tool here, but anything that is included with the system would work as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to *script* the clicking go the **Open in New Tabs** *menu item* of the target *folder* under **Bookmarks**, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do that:

```applescript
set bookmarksFolder to "Saved Tabs"

tell application "Safari" to activate

delay 1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "Open in New Tabs" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu item bookmarksFolder of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item "Bookmarks" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Safari"
```

Just change `"Saved Tabs"` in the first line of *code* to the actual *name* of the target *folder* on the **Bookmarks** *menu*.

Here is something a bit more robust…

I have different sets of **URLs** that I group into different *windows* by themselves, and have made an **AppleScript** *application* from the *code*. You can use the *example* **AppleScript** *code* below to do the same:

```applescript
set myURLs to {¬
    "https://somedomain.com", ¬
    "https://somedomain.com", ¬
    "https://somedomain.com", ¬
    "https://somedomain.com", ¬
    "https://somedomain.com", ¬
    "https://somedomain.com", ¬
    "https://somedomain.com", ¬
    "https://somedomain.com"}

tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:first item of myURLs}
    activate
    tell window 1
        set bounds to {0, 22, 1136, 844}
        delay 1
        repeat with i from 2 to count myURLs
            set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:item i of myURLs})
            delay 2
        end repeat
        set current tab to fourth tab
    end tell
end tell
```

Obviously `"https://somedomain.com"` is just a place holder for the real **URL**. The `set bounds …` and `set current tab …` *commands* can be adjusted to your liking or omitted.

I called the **AppleScript** *application* **My Regular Sites**, gave it a nice icon through the **Get Info** *window* method, and put it in the **Dock**.

This make it real easy to open **Safari** with a *window* containing my regular sites.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, @user3439894, this is exactly what I was looking for. One thing that tripped me up trying to use your first script is that my folder was in the "Favorites" folder (as a subfolder). So it's just a matter of putting it as a top-level folder in the bookmarks.

Comment: @Carlos, If you want to leave it in the **Favorites** _folder_, just add `of menu 1 of menu item "Favorites" ¬` after: `menu item bookmarksFolder of ¬`