# AppleScript to prompt for url input, open url in safari, then open bookmark with specific name

Tags: applescript, safari, bookmarks, javascript

I have a bookmark that runs some JavaScript code on the website the user has open at the time of running the bookmark - I'm aware there is a way using AppleScript to execute JavaScript on a Safari page but this requires 'Allow JavaScript from Apple Events' which I'm trying to avoid.

I'd like the script to ask for the user to enter a url, it will then open a new window with this page and then it will click the bookmark which will itself run some JavaScript on the open page.

So far, by looking at existing posts here on StackExchange, I've been able to get it to open bookmarks in different tabs, but I'm struggling to amend it to open a specific named bookmark on the page the script has opened.

Would appreciate any help anyone can give!

EDIT 1: The code that I'm amending from: [In Safari, can a set of bookmarks in a folder be opened programmatically (e.g. using AppleScript)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392459/in-safari-can-a-set-of-bookmarks-in-a-folder-be-opened-programmatically-e-g-u)

EDIT 2: Here's my latest code revision:

@user3439894 I've changed my code to

```
tell application "Safari" to activate

delay 1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "Google" of ¬
        application process "Safari"
```

with there being a bookmark titled 'Google' - I wasn't sure whether to keep the line 'application process "Safari"' or not, but whether its kept in or removed I get "Can't get menu item 'Google' of application process 'Safari'"

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: @nohillside just added the link to the code I'm amending and embedded within my post

Comment: You can change `Open in New Tabs` in `click menu item "Open in New Tabs" of ¬` to the _name_ of the target _bookmark_, or use the _index value_, e.g. `1` or whatever _number_ it is in the _list_ of the  `bookmarksFolder` _menu_ to have it click that _bookmark_.

Comment: As to other coding issues, there are plenty of answers already out there that do what you are asking. I know because I written them numerous times.  You can use the [display dialog](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW12) _command_ to prompt for the **URL**

Comment: @user3439894 I've updated my original post with your suggested changes but I don't think I've implemented it correctly as it's returning an error

Comment: You did not do as I suggested!  The link you've removed and the other _code_ works as advertised!

Comment: To be frank, your question is not totally clear in that you have not accurately described where on the **Bookmarks** menu the _bookmark_ titled 'Google' is located. In other words, is in on the main _menu_, or in a _folder_ of the main _menu_? Also I'd like to see the **JavaScript** _code_ that's in the target _bookmark_. Actually, the entire _source code_ of the target _bookmark_.

Comment: I'm sure if I had done as you originally suggested it would work, but clearly I've not understood your explanation. The bookmark is not within a folder, it is within the parent bookmark area, if that's any help.

Comment: RE: "The bookmark is not within a folder, it is within the parent bookmark area, if that's any help." --  If it's on the main **Bookmarks** _menu_, then use e.g.: `tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Google" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Bookmarks" of menu bar 1 of application process "Safari"`

Comment: JSYK My original comment was based on your original modification of my _code_ from the linked answer in which you showed `set bookmarksFolder to "test_folder"` and had there been a _folder_ of that name with the target _bookmark_, then what I originally said would have worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like the script to ask for the user to enter a url, it will then open a new window with this page and then it will click the bookmark which will itself run some JavaScript on the open page.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set theURL to ""

repeat while theURL is ""
    set theURL to ¬
        the text returned of ¬
            (display dialog "Enter the URL:" default answer ¬
                "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2)
end repeat

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:theURL}
end tell

my waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "Google" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item "Bookmarks" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Safari"


--  # Handler #

to waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()
    --  # Wait for page to finish loading in Safari.
    --  # This works in **macOS Catalina** and 
    --  # macOS Big Sur and may need adjusting for
    --  # other versions of macOS.
    tell application "System Events" to repeat until ¬
        exists (buttons of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading
```

**Notes:**

> I have a bookmark that runs some JavaScript code on the website the user has open at the time of running the bookmark.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* does exactly what was asked on the quoted portion of the question show at the top of this answer, however, the quoted portion of the question show at the start of this **Notes:** *section*, I have no way to determine what it does or whether or not is will work as you not included it as asked in a comment under the question. So, if what's presented herein does not achieve your goal you are on your own as I will not respond further without you providing all of the requested information.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: This works pretty well! I really appreciate your time writing this up. Currently the only issue I seem to have is after the first time it is run it doesn't prompt for the url anymore, instead it remembers the previously input url.

Comment: Ah not to worry, I've edited it to reassign the url variable to an empty string and that seems to have done it - once again, thanks!

Comment: @srb7 I've changes the first line to `set ...` and that will resolve the issue.